# How does the CLR behaves while using an out paramerter, what is the role of garbage collector as soon as the method returns?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, garbage-collection, clr

To be more specific here, please see a code snippet below.

```
    // Consider the itemCollection has list of items
    // Consider the classItems is CollectionClass that is manipulated from somewhere
    foreach(var item in itemCollection)
    {
      List<string> someNameCollection;
      bool complete = false;
      // itemCollection will be have thousand of items
      // First parameter is single item and item.AnyItems means IEnumerable<AnyItem>
      // classItems is CollectionClass that is manipulated from somewhere
      if(DoSomething(item , item.Items, classItems, out someNameCollection , out complete )){
// if someNameCollection will be empty i will fill it in DoSomework() using the same foreach() logic that is used in DoSomething()
        DoSomework(someNameCollection, complete); 
      }
    }


    private bool DoSomething(Item item, IEnumerable<AnyItem> anyItems, CollectionClass classItems, out List<string> nameCollection, out bool complete )
    {
      bool isNeeded = false;
      complete = false;
      nameCollection = new List<string>();

      // loop for some parameter supplied, loop will run for 100k items
      foreach(var item in anyItems)
      {
         // may be isNeeded true here
         isNeeded = true;
         //if true break the loop
         // complete == true,  may be here
      }

      if(!isNeeded)
      {
        foreach(var item in classItems)
       {
         // item are any name string
         nameCollection.Add(item);
       }
      }
      // another loop doing something
      foreach()
      {
         // uses the nameCollection here depending upon
      }

       foreach(var item in nameCollection)
       { 
          foreach()
         {
           // play with other things here
           // do some manipulations
           // may be, isNeeded = true here, if true break
         }
       }

       // and isNeeded is either true or false will only be determined may be before the end of the method

       return isNeeded;
    }
```

Now the thing is, as soon as the DoSomething() method returns it also has filled nameCollection List available. I believe that nameCollection will not be automatically garbage collected here, it will reside in the large object heap (will it be?), even though the method returns this object might not have been released from the memory (previously i have experienced this). Now again in the next call on DoSomething() the nameCollection will be filled and returned and it resides in the memory and it is not cleared, though we are creating a new instance everytime.

Do the same behavior exists as i describe above ? If not, what is the behavior here. If those collection object resides in memory, how can i flush it without affecting my out parametrized List ? If the collection object do not reside in memory, how does the out parameter get the collection object ?

It will be much more appreciated if anyone could describe me the core behavior here. I will be more than happy to clear my wrong concepts and add the right one.

Comment: It would be easier to reason about your code if you use two different names: one for the parameter, and one for the variable in the calling code. Additionally, your code doesn't currently compile. It's also not *really* clear what you're asking - objects are garbage collected at some point after they're last used, that's all. So if you don't keep a reference to the list created by the "previous" `DoSomething` call, it will eventually be garbage collected...

Comment: Also, you almost never need a `out` parameter. There are better ways in most cases.

Comment: @JonSkeet i have updated the names, and please do not worry about the complie. The objects ae not garbage collected when the method returns, i have expereinced this previously but i was not using out paramter i was simply manipulating the collection and returning it but when i did some work after the method complete i found the object still residing in the larger object heap.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel how costly will be using the out parameter. And what might be alternative to above scenario because i need the collection eventually if method is true, please see the updated code.

Comment: @user2991876 `out` doesn't cost anything in real terms - it is just passing the value of a local (which happens to be a list) vs passing the address of a local - `ldloc` vs `ldloca` in IL terms. The *list allocations* is more of a problem -  personally, I would do things to avoid having to allocate the list every time. As I already said: passing in a list for the method to manipulate would work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack is one of your GC "roots". In this case, the local is formally declared in the stack-frame of the calling code (we know that because `ldloca` only makes sense for formally declared locals - not ambient undeclared values on the stack), so the GC doesn't have to do anything more than walk the stack-frame inspecting the locals (and the remaining stack window, but that is more complex). Ultimately, to the GC, this is no different to a local variable *inside* a method:

```
SomeObject foo = new SomeObject();
```

As a side note: your list allocation is redundant and wasteful, and could be just:

```
List<string> nameCollection;
bool complete = false;
// DoSomething will be called thousand of times
if(DoSomething(out nameCollection, complete )){ // do the further task }
```

However, if it was me, and `DoSomething` is being called thousands of  times, I probably *would* allocate it outside the method, and treat the contents as discardable (call `Clear()` at the start of the method), and pass the list *in* - to avoid lots of list / array allocations.

Comment: *your list allocation is redundant and wasteful, and could be just:* if you want to do a complete job, even the `= false` is not necessary, because `DoSomething` is `out bool`

Comment: @marc i have updated the things a bit, i need to let you know one thing, previously while i was doing a memory profiling, there was a method which returned a very large collection object. And the method was called multiple times, but on every call i found the collection inside the method not being garbage collected, it only cleared while application closed. For this reason i was worried same happens here, in that method i could not clear the collection i could only make it null, because once cleared empty was returned. Making it null did not make it garbage collected then too.

Comment: @xanatos I can only assume the return value and the out-bool mean different things; either way: a bool on the stack is not an allocation, so it isn't all that meaningful to worry about it

Comment: @user2991876 GC is non-deterministic; I can't comment on the specific case without context - there *are* ways to inadvertently (but predictable) cause an object to be reachable - badly considered event subscriptions are one common way of doing it

Comment: @HenkHolterman in the actual code i have not made it redundant, i actually missed while questioning.

Comment: @MarcGravell yes i had lot of event associated within the application, they might be the reason for making the GC un -predictable. I am considering all your suggestions as answer but enforce your comment here "personally, I would do things to avoid having to allocate the list every time", can you please elaborate according to code above and write some lines what actually are you saying about. I will much appreciate it.

Comment: @user2991876 all I'm saying is that you could pass the list *in* (rather than *out*), and just `Add` (or whatever) inside the method; then if the caller is looping, they can allocate a single buffer *once*, and call the method any number of times, re-using the same list (and backing array) each time; much fewer allocations. Just remember to `Clear()` it at appropriate times.

Comment: @MarcGravell something to say here, on each iteration the nameCollection will have different number of items, (i.e. if it has for example items "abc,"cd" on first iteration on next will have "cf","ht" the list will be entirely different each time). And the same nameCollection is needed for the DoSomework(), please see the updated code above. For this reason i have to out the nameCollection because i need it on the successor method and cannot keep it static. What do you say ? Do you have better idea than using a list as out here, if so please do write me.

Comment: @MarcGravell the foreach loop needs to run for more than 100k times so that i cannot use the same on the DoSomework() method. I am trying to reducing the loop to call multiple times, because in DoSomework() i need to do exactly the same done in DoSomething() foreach loop. Thats why i am keeping the list as out so i can re-use if true in DoSomework().

Comment: @user2991876 that is completely irrelevant; consider: `var list = new List(); foreach(...) { list.Clear(); if(SomeMethod(list)) { DoSomething(list); }}` - we have only allocated *one* list, and have re-used it throughout

Comment: @MarcGravell i need to say something, i have plenty of codes below the foreach() loop in DoSomething(). They also uses the same nameCollection but do not change on those, and the true or false of the method are also determined below the foreach() loop. So if not true i should not go to DoSomework(). Just ignore the complete == true on foreach() loop (it is never true here), it might be true on the codes below that or not at all. So it is determined only at the end of the method if it is true or false. I cannot call the DoSomework() inside here because if false i may not have to call it at all.

Comment: @MarcGravell more info, i have other objects(parameters) that also needs to be manipulate before i can call DoSomework(), DoSomework() accepts other parameter too, that are determined below the foreach() loop in DoSomething().

Comment: @MarcGravell i have updated code, please view it, hope everything makes clear here, there are more codes but removed for the sake of simplicity. I need your suggestion now based on this.

Comment: @xanatos - the JIT optimizes away any initializations to default values.